# Setting the attributes of a struct in an array of structs with fscanf

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

**The Seg Fault was not occuring due to ScanF, it was due to a problem with my Main function.**

I'm trying to read in some data files, and my program is seg faulting when I try and use fscanf. Here's what I have:

```
while(fscanf(fr, "%d%s%d%d", riderArray[numberOfRiders].arrivalTime, riderArray[numberOfRiders].riderNumber,    riderArray[numberOfRiders].floorArrival, riderArray[numberOfRiders].floorDestination)!= EOF)
     {
     numberOfRiders++;
     }
```

The intended goal being, each line (which is guaranteed to be of the format `int string int int`) is parsed into a struct, until all the data in the `file fr` is read.

Is it doable this way?

I suppose the alternative would simply be:

```
while(fscanf(fr, "%d%s%d%d", &temp1, &tempS, &temp2, &temp3)!= EOF)
     {
         riderArray[numberOfRiders].riderNumber = temp1;
         etc. etc.
     numberOfRiders++;
     }
```

using the temp variables to avoid having to combine fscanf, structs, and arrays entirely (which would probably be cleaner to look at, anyway.

Here's the Struct:

```
typedef struct rider
{
    char  riderNumber[5];
    int  timeWaiting;
    int  jobLength;
    int  arrivalTime;
    int  floorArrival;
    int  floorDestination;

} rider;
```

Comment: Could you provide the definition of the struct?

Comment: @Blag -- That's a good point. Done.

Comment: That first item should be `char riderNumber[5]` (assuming you don't want an array of pointers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give fscanf some pointers:

```
while(
    fscanf(fr, "%d%s%d%d",
        &riderArray[numberOfRiders].arrivalTime,
        riderArray[numberOfRiders].riderNumber,    // this is already a pointer
        &riderArray[numberOfRiders].floorArrival,
        &riderArray[numberOfRiders].floorDestination
    ) != EOF
)
```

Comment: -1: you don't know whether the struct members are defined as pointers or not, and the parentheses are unnecessary

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: true, but usually when fscanf-like functions seg fault there's something wrong with the parameters. at least, these are the first thing i check. and parentheses are for readability, i like them :)

Answer (score 1):

I notice you aren't using pointers in your real code, even though you have pointers in your temp example.

```
fscanf(fr, "%d%s%d%d", &riderArray[numberOfRiders].arrivalTime, riderArray[numberOfRiders].riderNumber, &riderArray[numberOfRiders].floorArrival, &riderArray[numberOfRiders].floorDestination)
```

Note that `riderNumber` doesn't use an "address-of" operator (`&`) because it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly doable the way you describe first.  It would be a little easier to debug if we have the declaration and definition of your struct.  One thing I notice is that `riderArray[numberOfRiders].arrivalTime` appears to be a value; in `fscanf` you need it to be the *address* of the value.